# getting the Material Design TimePicker - android?

Tags: android, widget, material-design, timepicker

if i use `TimePicker`/`TimePickerDialog` in my app i'm getting `timePickerMode="spinner"` styled widget though what i'm looking for is `timePickerMode="clock"`. this is the style I've done

```
<style name="timePicker_dialog parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
<item name="timePickerMode">clock</item>
</style>
```

and I've set this res as the style in the `TimePicker` via it's `TimePickerDialog()`, butt i'm still getting the spinner. is it device dependent? my phone is running v4.4.4? if not, what am i missing here. thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

try it

Answer (score 2):

As of late 2020, `MaterialTimePicker` is in the beta version of the Material package.
Therefore you can add the following to your app Gradle:

```
dependencies { ...
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-beta01'
}
```

And then use `MaterialTimePicker` [like so](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/timepicker/TimePickerMainDemoFragment.java):

```
      MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
          .setTimeFormat(clockFormat)
          .setHour(hour)
          .setMinute(minute)
          .build();

      materialTimePicker.show(requireFragmentManager(), "fragment_tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add dependencies `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`
i think use appcompat's theme under 5.0
`parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`