# How to pick time using material design?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android, android-timepicker

how to pick a time using material:1.3.0-alpha01, I am looking time picker following screenshot, which I found in material io.

I tried date picker is working [image: material time picker]

Material Date picker

```
//Creating a MaterialDatePicker.Builder instance that gives us a single date selector.
val builder : MaterialDatePicker.Builder<*> = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker() // 1
//Building-up the MaterialDatePicker by calling a builder.build function
val picker : MaterialDatePicker<*> = builder.build()  // 2
//Display the Material Date Picker.
picker.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())   // 3
```

Simple Time picker

```
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                //textView.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time)
            }
            val time = TimePickerDialog(context, timeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
            time.setTitle("")
            time.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: MATERIAL TIME PICKER]
To use **MATERIAL TIME PICKER**, add the following dependency to your project's build.gradle file:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

Kotlin time picker using material:1.3.0-alpha02

```
val timePickerDialog = MaterialTimePicker.newInstance();
            timePickerDialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "fragment_tag");
            // Types of formats for the time pickeer
            timePickerDialog.setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)//CLOCK_24H
            timePickerDialog.setListener { dialog: MaterialTimePicker ->
                val newHour = dialog.hour
                val newMinute = dialog.minute
}
```

Comment: is it available in java

Comment: it is in kotlin not java and only show date picker not time picker

Comment: adnan ref here:
ref this link

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/timepicker/TimePickerMainDemoFragment.java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553241/getting-the-material-design-timepicker-android

Comment: thanks , is it possible to add am or pm after time ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381985/how-do-i-set-am-pm-in-a-timepicker

Answer (score 15):

You can use the new **`MaterialTimePicker`** introduced with the Material Components Library.

**Note:** this code **requires** at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha03`**.

```
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker

val materialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
    .build()

materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    val newHour: Int = materialTimePicker.hour
    val newMinute: Int = materialTimePicker.minute
}
```

[image]

Using the same code with:

```
val materialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
    .build()

materialTimePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "fragment_tag")
```

[image]