# How to pick time using MaterialDesign's MaterialTimePicker in Java (android)?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, material-design

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882368/how-to-pick-time-using-material-design) about picking time on positive click of the time picker from Material Design. I am struggling with doing it in Java.

My current codes:

```
        final MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
                                                .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
                                                .build();
    pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_tag");
        }
    });
```

I am thinking about writing something like  `materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<>())`, but I am not sure how to fill the blank. My goal is to get the hour and minutes from the time picker.

Comment: Have u seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63147357/5202007

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pick time using material design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882368/how-to-pick-time-using-material-design)

Answer (score 0):

Using MaterialTimePicker that was introduced with Material Components Library.

This requires version *1.3.0-alpha03* or the latest

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
          .setTimeFormat(clockFormat)
          .setHour(hour)
          .setMinute(minute)
          .build();

materialTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_tag")
```

[check sample code here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/timepicker/TimePickerMainDemoFragment.java)