# Return MaterialTimePicker

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Been searching how to impliment the MaterialTimePicker to old TimerPickerDialog

[How to pick time using material design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882368/how-to-pick-time-using-material-design)

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/timepicker/TimePickerMainDemoFragment.java

My Current Solution is this but too old

```
  return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

the code

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

    }
}
```

From this

[image: old picker]

to this

[image]

Comment: Try to change your app theme to a light theme

Comment: nothing happens even i change to light theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
            .build();


    pick.setOnClickListener(v -> materialTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            DiConstant.TIME_PICKER));

    materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(dialog -> {
        int newHour = materialTimePicker.getHour();
        int newMinute = materialTimePicker.getMinute();
        String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", newHour, newMinute);
        pick.setText(time);
    });
```

Where pick is the view you show selected time in.
To answer your comment you could try

```
return materialTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "TIME_PICKER");
```

Comment: the timepicker is DialogFragment

Comment: Yes, hence getSupportFragmentManager, the above code will show it in an Activity.

Comment: how can i return it

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'DiConstant' @SABANTO

Comment: Sorry about that, DiConstant.TIME_PICKER is a String constant. Should i have clarified that, choose any string you want there